# melt dataframe and group by using dplyr calculations in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, reshape2

My sample data 
`

```
structure(list(state = c("AP", "AP"), district = c("krishna", 
"guntur"), rate = c(170104.5156, 1343.78134), growth_in_2016 = c(0.3844595, 
0.3678), growth_in_2017 = c(0.444595, 0.8445), growth_in_2018 = c(0.323699, 
0.36213), growth_in_2019 = c(0.5777, 0.35256), growth_in_2020 = c(0.2669097, 
0.9097)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000026c1ef0>)
```

`

I'm trying to group by state and district and then calculate monthly growth rate from yearly.

Formula to calculate monthly is :(1+rates*growth_in_year)^(1/12) -1
Correct me if am wrong

`

```
state     district     date        rates
AP        krishna    2016-12-31       x
AP        krishna    2017-01-31       y
AP        krishna    2017-02-28       z
AP        krishna    2017-03-30       a
AP        krishna    2017-04-31       b
AP        krishna    2017-05-30       c
AP        krishna    2017-06-31       d
```

and so onn for other district too.
rates has to be in increasing order per each year for each district.
I would like to have in date format rather than in year format.

Comment: Why all `growth..` column have same names with different values?

Comment: @RonakShah Because it is based on State level, I made them to district level i,e growth is same as state level and base_point(rates) is different for districts.

Comment: Check your sample data again. You have five columns identically named "growth_in_2016", so for each row you have four (there is one duplicate) values for a single variable.

Comment: @heds1,that's how my data is.But I will edit my post by changing the growth_rate to see difference.

Comment: so for every `state` and `district` you want 12 rows for each year and the new calculated monthly would be the same for the entire year? In the example shared since you have data for 5 years each row would be expanded into 12 X 5 = 60 rows?

Comment: @RonakShah You are almost right,but new calculated monthly data should be incremental across each particular year.Eg: x,x+growth(for 1st month),x+growth(for 2nd month).....

Comment: @RonakShah I'm not sure about the formula, above formula is what I have tried.I was stuck getting monthly growth from yearly.or may be we should try `seq_len(12)/12` which changes values monthly.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

We can first `gather` data to long format, then `group_by` `state`, `district` and `year`, find the new monthly `rate`, extract the year from the column name and create a `list` of dates representing the last day of the month for the entire year and finally calculate cumulative sum of `rate` to get an incremental value for each month.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -(1:3)) %>%
  group_by(state, district, key) %>%
  mutate(rate = (1 + rate * value)^(1/12) - 1, 
         year = sub(".*(\\d{4})", "\\1", key),
        dates = list(seq(as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")),
                     as.Date(paste0(year, "-12-01")), by = "month")- 1)) %>%
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(rate = cumsum(rate)) %>%
  select(-year)


#  state district  rate key            value dates     
#  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <date>    
# 1 AP    krishna   1.52 growth_in_2016 0.384 2015-12-31
# 2 AP    krishna   3.04 growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-01-31
# 3 AP    krishna   4.56 growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-02-29
# 4 AP    krishna   6.08 growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-03-31
# 5 AP    krishna   7.60 growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-04-30
# 6 AP    krishna   9.12 growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-05-31
# 7 AP    krishna  10.6  growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-06-30
# 8 AP    krishna  12.2  growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-07-31
# 9 AP    krishna  13.7  growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-08-31
#10 AP    krishna  15.2  growth_in_2016 0.384 2016-09-30
# … with 110 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(state = c("AP", "AP"), district = c("krishna", 
"guntur"), rate = c(170104.5156, 1343.78134), growth_in_2016 = c(0.3844595, 
0.3678), growth_in_2017 = c(0.444595, 0.8445), growth_in_2018 = c(0.323699, 
0.36213), growth_in_2019 = c(0.5777, 0.35256), growth_in_2020 = c(0.2669097, 
0.9097)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Got the following error : `Error in seq.Date(as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")), as.Date(paste0(year,  : 
  'from' must be of length 1` when tried

Comment: @Lalitha seems to work for me on the data you have shared. Do you have any extra columns which is not shown in the data? Can you select and run only the same columns shown and run this again?

Comment: I'm using same data.Can you give me any clue.

Comment: @Lalitha I updated the post with the data I am using. Can you try using that?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` to do the rate calculation on the 'growth' column, then `gather` into 'long' format, remove the substring from 'date', grouped by 'state', 'district', get the `cumsum` of the 'value' column

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- df %>%
       mutate_at(vars(starts_with('growth')), list(~ (1 + rate * .)^(1/12) - 1)) %>% 
       gather(date, value, matches("growth")) %>%
       mutate(date = str_remove(date, ".*_")) %>%
       group_by(state, district) %>% 
       mutate(value = cumsum(value))
out %>%
  filter(district == "krishna")
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   state, district [1]
#  state district    rate date  value
#  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1 AP    krishna  170105. 2016   1.52
#2 AP    krishna  170105. 2017   3.07
#3 AP    krishna  170105. 2018   4.55
#4 AP    krishna  170105. 2019   6.16
#5 AP    krishna  170105. 2020   7.60
```

Comment: Got shown output by you, but here we just has year numbers instead of monthly projections.Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Lalitha Please fill the expected output in your post.  It is not clear what you wanted

Comment: Edited my question. Also my sample output shows I would like to  have in date format rather than having same year name with different growth rate. Please help me. Thanks in Advance